# rocket engine exhaust animation

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I want to animate a rocket launch but I don't know how I would make the rocket engine plume/exhaust. I'm thinking fire/smoke simulation but I don't know if that would work.

Thanks

---

I have tried smoke simulations but they don't look very realistic. Pic:

[image]

I want it to look more upside-down v-shaped and thinner. More like this:[image] and with a gradient between purple-white and orange. I want to make something like this with the white replaced with orange:

[image]

Comment: This might help-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p7B4h7eOdA

Comment: What have you tried and where *specifically* are you getting stuck?

Comment: @RayMairlot see my answer down below

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 thanks, but I want it to be more realistic and not low poly.

Comment: @liaiwen please don't use the answers section for anything other than answers. Clarifications or further information should be added to the original question. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your original post.

Answer (score 0):

add a uv sphere , cut it in half , scale it on the horizontal axis making it longer , then add a wave modifier and play with the values